# large files Download in Java using FileCopyUtils.copy

Tags: java, file, download

I wrote some codes to download files from the Sever to the clients machines:

```
   BufferedInputStream in = null;
                try {
                    in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileNpath));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String mimetype = servletContext.getMimeType(fileNpath);

                response.setBufferSize(fSize);
                response.setContentType(mimetype); 
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+ fileName + "\"");
                response.setContentLength(fSize); 


                try {
                    FileCopyUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream()); 
                    in.close();
                    response.getOutputStream().flush();
                    response.getOutputStream().close();  
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This code works fine for the files smaller than 8M but not for larger files. I will be grateful if you guys give me some hints.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: What happens? Do you get an exception or does it just hang?

Comment: When I deploy my app on tomcat it just transfers 8M (and sometimes 16M)  of a 75M file without showing any error messages. I only know the problem when I click to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to go on here.  In Tomcat there are various ways to set the maximum file upload size.

For example in the tomcat server.xml, there is a maxPostSize setting.  I really do not know enough about your server to say specifically where to look.

Comment: Thanks, my application server is Tomcat, I will increase maxPostSize to see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the heap size in tomcat solved the problem.

So I set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m in apache-tomcat-7.0.8\bin\catalina.bat

I also set maxPostSize="0"